# Invalid Syntax error for small python txt file writing program

Tags: python

I am trying to create / write to a txt file, however, the code I have obtained from https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html is not rendering.

```
def main():

f = open("JTF.txt", "w+")

for i in range(10)
    f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))

f.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

# The error i am receiving when I run the above code is as follows:
#     def main()
#             ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/l5rKoh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses whitespaced block syntax. In addition after a for loop you need to add `:`

```
def main():
    f = open("JTF.txt", "w+")

    for i in range(10):
        f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))

    f.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```